# Assign slice of variable lenght to column with method chaining

Tags: pandas, assign

I would like to assign a column a slice of variable lentgh of another column, but somehow it does not work as I expect, and I do not understand why:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

m = np.array([[1, 'AAAAA'],
               [2, 'BBBB'],
               [3, 'CCC']])

df = (pd.DataFrame(m, columns = ['id', 's1'])
        .assign(
                s2 = lambda x: x['s1'].str.slice(start=0, stop=x['s1'].str.len()-1))
        )

print(df)
```

which leads to

```
  id     s1  s2
0  1  AAAAA NaN
1  2   BBBB NaN
2  3    CCC NaN
```

However, I would expect the following:

```
  id     s1   s2
0  1  AAAAA AAAA
1  2   BBBB  BBB
2  3    CCC   CC
```

Any idea what happens here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `str[:-1]` for indexing all values of column without last:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(m, columns = ['id', 's1'])
        .assign(
                s2 = lambda x: x['s1'].str[:-1])
        )

print(df)
  id     s1    s2
0  1  AAAAA  AAAA
1  2   BBBB   BBB
2  3    CCC    CC
```

Your solution working only is use `apply` for check each row separately, like:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(m, columns = ['id', 's1'])
        .assign(
                s2 = lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: y['s1'][0:len(y['s1'])-1], axis=1))
        )

print(df)
  id     s1    s2
0  1  AAAAA  AAAA
1  2   BBBB   BBB
2  3    CCC    CC
```

Comment: thanks a lot - this is obviously the correct way of doing it. However, why does my approach not work? I should be able to count the number of characters and then subtract 1, no?

Comment: @divingTobi - I think problem is in your solution is passed length for each value different, so possible solution is use `apply`. But if want remove only last value passing `-1` is better.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your `slice()` `stop` arg, which only needs to be `-1`.

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(m, columns = ['id', 's1'])
        .assign(
                s2 = lambda x: x['s1'].str.slice(start=0, stop=-1)
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use apply for pandas like this:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                     

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2,3],"s1":["AAAAA","BBBB","CCC"]})           

In [3]: df                                                                      
Out[3]: 
   id     s1
0   1  AAAAA
1   2   BBBB
2   3    CCC

In [4]: df["s2"] = df["s1"].apply(lambda x: x[:-1])                             

In [5]: df                                                                      
Out[5]: 
   id     s1    s2
0   1  AAAAA  AAAA
1   2   BBBB   BBB
2   3    CCC    CC

In [6]:
```